# Double Rings of Amity

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, healing

The *Ring of Amity* from *Bigby Presents: Glory of the Giants* has a property that states:

> When you first attune to this ring, you can touch one willing creature and form a magical bond between the two of you. While this bond lasts, whenever you are subjected to a spell or magical effect that restores hit points, the bonded creature also receives the benefits of the spell or effect.

What happens if two player characters each attune a *ring of amity*, selecting each other as the bonded creature, and one of them pops a *goodberry* or drinks a *potion of healing*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They both receive the benefit of a *goodberry* or *potion of healing* once.

> the bonded creature also receives the benefits of the spell or effect.

It doesn't say that the ring produce the healing effect, just that the creature receives the benefits of the spell or effect. And since the first character already received that benefit that triggered the ring in the first place the second ring does nothing. Unless stated otherwise you don't benefit from the same spell or effect twice.

While this item is pretty badly written that is the only interpretation of the rules that makes any sense (and that any sane DM would make).

Comment: That said, while you alas can't get infinite healing this way, it does seem that a chain of _Rings of Amity_ ought to allow the whole party (or town or city or country, depending on just how enterprising you want to get) to benefit from a single healing spell cast on the first member of the chain. Close the chain in a loop to let everyone enjoy any healing spells cast on _any_ member of the chain.

Comment: (You _could_ argue that "receiving the benefit" of a spell indirectly via the bond doesn't count as "being subjected to" the spell, so the effect shouldn't propagate further. But the bond created by the ring is itself magical — it even explicitly _says_ so — so even under this interpretation any healing shared via the bond ought to count as a "magical effect that restores hit points" which could then be shared further by another _Ring of Amity_.)

Comment: Hm, it looks like there are some arguments in the other direction. I may have been a bit fast to accept the answer, as it happened to be the one I had *hoped* to hear. To not discourage people from exploring alternative answers, I'll unaccept it for now, and will reaccept if nobody comes back to make a more convincing answer the other way. I wholeheartedly agree with your last sentence. Were I ever to design any RPG rules, they would include a general rule that any combination of effects that allows unlimited/infinite effects will only work as a one time effect.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin There kinda sorta is such a rule, `The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine`, which if you squint can also mean that the same magical effect can't stack infinitely (or indeed at all). But still, it doesn't explicitly say that. Maybe because the core rules were written in a way that this scenario shouldn't arise. For example with Warding Bond it's expressly stated that being affected by a second Warding Bond immediately ends the first one.